# nose2.main() verbose output

Tags: python, nose2

I'm writing a separate nose2 tests.py for my program and because I want it to run on both Windows and Linux fairly seamlessly I've decided to forgo using the normal commandline nose2 and instead import it in the file and run it from there.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose2
    nose2.main()
```

This works fine, no problems. But I'd like the verbose output and I can't see how to get it to do this. I've tried:

```
nose2.main("-v")
nose2.main(kwargs="-v")
nose2.main(args="-v")
```

Anyone know how to get the imported version of nose2 to run in verbose mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `PluggableTestProgram` class [accepts the same parameters](http://nose2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/main.html?highlight=verbosity) of `unittest.TestProgram`, you can pass `verbosity` to the `main` function as such:

```
nose2.main(verbosity=2)  # default is 1
```

See: `Unittest.main` [documentation about verbosity](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html?highlight=verbosity#unittest.main)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into the documentation more for other options.